# Errors with XeLaTeX after installing TexLive 2022

Tags: xetex, texlive, ebgaramond

I just upgraded to TexLive 2022 (I was using version 2016). Now XeLaTeX is failing to typeset my files.

I am using subfiles to keep common preamble and macros in one place only and several smaller files that reference this.

File: test-format.tex:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%, letterpaper
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,letterpaper,draft]{memoir}

\usepackage{ifxetex}

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=TeX}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noindentfirst]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfiles}          
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\usepackage{datetime}

\microtypesetup{babel=true,final}
```

Then file test.tex

```
\documentclass[test-format.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

Typesetting this produces this output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-29>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfiles/subfiles.cls
Document Class: subfiles 2020/11/14 v2.2 Multi-file projects (class)
Preamble taken from file `test-format.tex'
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/import/import.sty)
(./test-format.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2022/02/20 v3.7q configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem12.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/dcolumn.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/delarray.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/xebabel.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-spanish/spanish.ldf))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc-greekbasic.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memhfixc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfiles/subfiles.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/svgnam.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebgaramond/ebgaramond.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
Missing character: There is no   (U+0020) in font [EBGaramond-Initials.otf]/OT!
Missing character: There is no   (U+0020) in font [EBGaramond-Initials.otf]/OT!
Missing character: There is no   (U+0020) in font [EBGaramond-Initials.otf]/OT:
language=dflt;!
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-xetex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fundus-calligra/calligra.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lettrine/lettrine.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/minifp/minifp.sty)
Loading lettrine.cfg
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lettrine/lettrine.cfg))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ragged2e/ragged2e.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fourier/fourier-orns.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datetime/datetime.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fmtcount/fmtcount.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fmtcount/fcprefix.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fmtcount/fcnumparser.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty)

Package fmtcount Warning: \ordinal already defined use \FCordinal instead. on i
nput line 466.

) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datetime/datetime-defaults.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datetime/dt-spanish.def)))))
*
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you have not shown any input and only fragments of the log so almost impossible to offer any help, but the final `*` prompt means tex reached the end of file without seeing `\end{document}` and is waiting for input.

Comment: You didn't post any example that's causing it. But in my experience LaTeX acts weird if you just upgrade instead of a installing a completely fresh distribution. I would suggest uninstalling completely and then reinstalling after restarting

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have improved the question with full log and sample files.

Comment: @Masum: Technically it is not upgrade, TexLive installs a new version in an entirely new directory, maintaining the previous installation intact.

Comment: How will Texlive know which distribution to use and what's to prevent from any conflict arising? Specially if both distributions are in environment variables, I see that as a recipe for a hazard

Comment: @Masum This is how it is done, at least for the Mac. You can see it being described here: https://tug.org/mactex/faq/index.html#qm02

TexLive GUI App in the Mac allows you select a release, I believe it works using symlinks, but I don't know the details.

Comment: @Masum I have several texlive installed (currently the system tex plus texlive 2020,2021,2022.  You just need to set the PATH to the appropriate bin directory, all tex-related search paths are specified  relative to the location of the binary, so if you run the texlive 2020 pdflatex it will find files in the texlive/2020 input tree.

Comment: I see. I had issues with MikTeX upgrades before. Texlive might be different

Answer (score 1):

The `*` prompt means TeX read past the end of the file and is waiting for user input.

You can reproduce with a simpler test file

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{microtype}

\microtypesetup{babel=true,final}
```

Which produces

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./cc263.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-04-29>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/memoir.cls
Document Class: memoir 2022/02/20 v3.7q configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/memoir/mem10.clo)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/dcolumn.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/delarray.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty)
(./textcase.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfiles/subfiles.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/import/import.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pdftex.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg)))
*
```

That is not an error, It is an intractive prompt, so you can type tex commands such as

```
*\begin{document}
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./cc263.aux)

Package microtype Warning: You did not load the babel or the polyglossia packag
e.
(microtype)                The `babel' option won't have any effect.

(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg)
*hello

*\end{document}
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./cc263.aux)</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on cc263.pdf (1 page, 11170 bytes).
Transcript written on cc263.log.
```

Which produces the output

[image]

Of course adding the commands interactively just affects his run, so to effect a permanent change you would need to add

```
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

To the end of the above file.

Adding that to the end of your `test-format.tex` would similarly stop tex reading past the end of the file when being used for `subfiles` processing.

Comment: I was wondering what the asterisk meant, thank you for clarifying it. 

In any case, I was typesetting my second file (_test.tex_) which has the _\begin{document}_ and _\end{document}_, so I nothing was missing.  It all worked again by removing package _subfiles_ from the _test-format.tex_ file. It's all good now.

Comment: @user6722996 removing the package avoids the error but completely negates the purpose of using subfiles at all. personally I wouldn't use it but if you do use it the idea is that your main document _and_ your sub documents are complete

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

Commenting package *subfiles* in the *test-format.tex* file fixes the problem.

```
%\usepackage{subfiles}
```